# Add nuxt.js plugin only in modern bundle

Tags: plugins, polyfills, nuxt.js

I want to add a polyfill via a nuxt-plugin. I am also building two bundles - one for modern browsers and one for older ones.

nuxt-config.js

```
export default: {
  ...,
  modern: true,
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/polyfills', mode: 'client' }
  ],
  ...
}
```

plugins/polyfill.js:

```
require('intersection-observer')
```

Problem is that regardless if I serve in modern-mode or not, this piece of JavaScript is always added to my bundles (as intended).

***Question:*** Is it possible to only add this plugin if the bundle is not of type "***modern***"?

In my case I want to include the intersection-observer polyfill, but only on older browsers to save some bytes.

Comment: you can do it in build.extend. Let me know if dont figure it out and i will create a proper answer then

Comment: @Aldarund thx for the hint! But I cant figure out how to add the plugin :(

Comment: I think with this method you can only extend the default webpack config